# Homotopy Continuation solution of system of polynomials

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I have very large systems (>20) of polynomial (max degree 3) equations that I would like to find a solution to.  I'm not interested in all solutions as presumably there are too many (a huge number based on Bézout's bound), but I would like to find a single solution.  I haven't been able to achieve this using FindInstance (program hangs) or FindRoot (singular jacobian message).  I suspect the latter problem is due to not being able to guess a good initial starting point for the root.  It is known that the Homotopy continuation method avoids the problem of having to choose a starting point for the initial root.

My question is: does FindInstance use Homotopy continuation method?

If it does then I'm out of ideas.  If it doesn't then I will try to implement the method in another way.  All I've been able to find is the following statement 
https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-algebraic-computation/high-performance-numeric-solution-of-polynomial-sy.html

saying that the method is "selected when appropriate" but I'm not sure if its implemented for FindInstance.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Often, the `FindRoot` singular Jacobian problem can be solved by varying the initial guess slightly.  In any case, please provide a sample of your problem for readers to consider.

Comment: the explicit equations are posted here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134264/perturb-initial-points-until-findroot-succeeds?noredirect=1#comment362218_134264   but that didn't lead to anything much, so Ive tried to consider the system from another perspective (homotopy continuation)...or atleast I think its a different perspective, hence the above Q.  I should add that I tried changing around working and machine precision when encountering the singular Jacobian as well as varying initial guess

Comment: What is the smallest set of equations that exhibits this problem?  Your question above suggests that 20 may be the minimum size, but your earlier question gave a set of 45 equations.  Readers are more likely to analyze smaller sets of equations.  Also, if the decimal numbers in the equations were obtained from rational numbers, it may be better to use those instead.

Comment: I think you can use `NSolve[newComboEqs, vars, Method -> "Homotopy"]` to get the method. It runs for a long time, too, your linked question case. (I did not wait for it to finish.)

Comment: thanks Michael, I was just going to try to direct you guys to this question too.  The fact that it runs for ages (forever I imagine) is not unexpected as there are potentially an enormous number of solutions to find...thats why I'm interested in particular in FindInstance.  I thought my chances might be better if all I wanted was one solution.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I've posted a simpler rational system in an edit to my previous question that is linked in the comment above.  thanks

Comment: @bbgodfrey it seems also possible that an initial guess could have converged to a trivial solution when `FindRoot` reports singular Jacobian issue?

Comment: @Nobody  If there are multiple solutions, then `FindRoot` can converge to any of them, depending on initial conditions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks a lot. I actually also want to ask if a solution probably correct (within a certain tolerance) even `FindRoot` reported "line search decreased steps to within tolerance specified by AG or PG but was unable to..." or "singular Jacobian"?

Comment: @Nobody  The two error messages you mentioned are different in character.  The singular Jacobian error is addressed in the question above.  In general, there is no reason to suppose that the solution provided is accurate.  The answer returned with the line search error message often is accurate to a degree.  To see if it is, run the computation again with `MaxIterations` much larger than the default `100` to see whether the message goes away.  See the `FindRoot`  documentation.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thank you. "...run again with `MaxIterations` much larger..." Should we use the obtained solution as the new initial guess in such a re-computation?

Comment: @Nobody  You could, and it might save a bit of time.

Comment: @bbgodfrey according to the line search error message, it also mentioned more digits of working precision to meet the tolerances. After successive increasing `MaxIterations`, e.g. 200, 400, 600, the message remains, should I increase the `WorkingPrecision` as well?

Comment: @Nobody  Increasing `WorkingPrecision` might help, depending on the details of the problem.  May I suggest that you post a Question, including the code you are using, to obtain more effective assistance.